# Saving output of for-loop for every iteration

Tags: r

I am currently working on an imputation project where I need to evaluate my methods of imputation. I have my incomplete dataframe with NAs from which I calculate the missing rate for every column/variable. My second data frame contains the complete cases which I extracted from the first data frame. I now want to simulate the missingness structure of the real data in the frame containing the complete cases. the data frame with the generated NAs get stored in the object "result" as you can see in the code. If I now want to replicate this code and thus generate 100 different data frames like "result", how do I replicate and save them separately?

I'm a beginner and would be really thankful for your answers!

I tried to put my loop which generates the NAs in another loop which contains the replicate() command and counts from 1:100 and saves these 100 replicated data frames but it didn't work at all.

```
result = data.frame(res0=rep(NA, dim(comp_cas)[1]))
for (i in 1:length(Z32_miss_item$miss_per_item)) {
  dat = comp_cas[,i]
  missRate = Z32_miss_item$miss_per_item[i]
  cat (i, " ", paste0(dat, collapse=",") ," ", missRate, "!\n")                  
  df <- data.frame("res"= GenMiss(x=dat, missrate = missRate), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(df) = gsub("res", paste0("Var", i), colnames(df))
  result = cbind(result, df)
}
result = result[,-1]
```

I expect that every data frame of the 100 runs get saved in a separate .rda file in my project folder.

also, is imputation and the evaluation of fitness of the latter beginner stuff in r or at what level of proficiency am I if you take a look at the code that I posted?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to guess what exactly you are doing without some dummy data. But it is fine to have loops within loops and to save data.frames. Firstly, I would avoid the `replicate` function here as it has a strange syntax and just stick with plain loops. Secondly, you must make sure that the loops have different indexes (i.e. `for(i ...` should be surrounded by, say, `for(j ...` since functions can loop outside their scope in R. Finally, use `saveRDS` rather than `save`, as you can then have each object (`data.frame`) saved in separate `.rds` files. The `save` function is designed for saving your whole workspace so that you can pick up where you left off.

```
fun <- function(i){
  df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5))
  names(df) <- paste0("x",i)
  df
}

for(j in 1:100){
  res <- data.frame(id=1:5)
  for(i in 1:10){
    res <- cbind(res, fun(i))
  }
  saveRDS(res, sprintf("replication_%s.rds",j))
}
```